# Agora.io event on videochat creation

Tags: java, videochat, agora.io

I'm using Agora.io to create video chat between two people. On server side, I have recorder plugin that is used to record all chats between users.
My question is can I get notified some how (or create some listener) when channel is created so I will start recording? I need to get such notification from agora server and not from client if possible

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the recording really depends on how you want to implement it. Channels (within the Agora.io platform) don't have a "ready" state. Once a user joins the channel, the channel now exists, first user to join the channel is a broadcaster (*unless explicitly set as a viewer prior to joining a broadcast channel*)

Regardless of the logic you choose to implement, with all of the Agora.io SDKs there is a callback event for when the local user has joined the channel and one whenever a remote user joins a channel, so you decide when to programmatically call the recording server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is apparently wrong design when client explicitly 
 requests record start from server.

Comment: Client should not send request for record start

Comment: considering that the backend is managed by Agora's platform there isn't a server so the only way to expose this functionality is on the client side.